# Not able to pick value from apex:inputTextarea using javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community, salesforcedx

I am trying to pick value in `apex:inputTextArea` field. There are two input fields. One is `apex:input` and other is `apex:inputTextarea`. Here is my `visualforce` code -

```
<apex:form >
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>DRIP Ts&amp;Cs (Append):</td>
<td id="DRIPTsCs_{!house.id}">
<apex:input size="75" html-maxlength="500" value="{!house.DRIPTsCs}" Type="text" onblur="DRIPTsCs_Change('{!house.id}', '{!house.DRIPTsCs}');"> //Field# 1
</apex:input> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DRIP Ts&amp;Cs (Replace):</td>
<td id="DRIPTsCsReplace_{!house.id}">
<apex:inputTextarea html-maxlength="2500" value="{!house.DRIPTsCsReplace}" rows="5" style="width:553px" onblur="DRIPTsCsReplace_Change('{!house.id}', '{!house.DRIPTsCsReplace}');"> //Field# 2
</apex:inputTextarea> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>  
</apex:form>
```

Here is my `javascript` code to pick values -

```
function DRIPTsCs_Change(houseId, DRIPTsCs){
    var DRIPTsCs = $("#DRIPTsCs_"+houseId).find("input").val(); //This value is getting captured by variable.
          if(DRIPTsCs === null || DRIPTsCs === undefined)
              DRIPTsCs = '';
                }
                
function DRIPTsCsReplace_Change(houseId, DRIPTsCsReplace){
    var DRIPTsCsReplace = $("#DRIPTsCsReplace_"+houseId).find("input").val(); //This value is not getting captured by the variable.
         if(DRIPTsCsReplace === null || DRIPTsCsReplace === undefined)
               DRIPTsCsReplace = '';
                }
```

If I simply replace `apex:inputTextarea` with `apex:input` in my visualforce code for field# 2, variable `DRIPTsCsReplace` in function: `DRIPTsCsReplace_Change(houseId, DRIPTsCsReplace)` start capturing values.
Can anyone please help me how I can capture the `apex:inputTextarea` value in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `<apex:inputTextarea` gets converted to `textarea`.

You can simply use :

```
$("#DRIPTsCsReplace_"+houseId).find('textarea').val()
```

Comment: Thanks Nagendra....That worked